# Chart.js legend position error

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I try to move the legend of a pie chart(created with Chart.js 2.0) to left or right, but I always get an error. The bottom and top option works.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: optionLabels,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Resources',
                data: optionData,
                backgroundColor: optionColor,
                borderColor: "white",
                borderWidth: 1,

            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'left'
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

Is there a library bug or something similar?

Comment: are you sure the error is occurring due to `position: 'left'`? coz it doesn't seem like..

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ I suspect that it occurs on position:left and right also because it does not occur on position: 'top' and position: 'bottom'. The last two works as expected.

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ The version was 2.2.0,  I updated it to 2.7.0 and it works, you can submit your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris How to update version 2.2.0 to 2.7.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are using an old version of ChartJS *(which might have this bug)*.

Make sure you use the latest version of ChartJS, which is `2.7.0` at-the-moment.

see a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/0mjp0tsa/).